# how can i search .txt files in a folder in C?

Tags: c, file

I want to get file extensions without using standart libraries in C. so basically i want to search for `.txt` files in a folder which includes `.png`, `.txt`, `.jpg` files.

I don't have a certain code to show, although while I was searching I found a code which includes `<dirent.h>` and everybody was saying this code cannot be done without that library. Can't I do it without that? and also in some websites they were saying `<dirent.h>` is only a library for Linux. I'm using MacOS.

code was this: [How can I get only txt files from directory in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976733/how-can-i-get-only-txt-files-from-directory-in-c)
error is this:

```
Member reference base type 'char [1024]' is not a structure or union.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: _without using standard libraries in C_ you cannot traverse and get the folder tree. Darwin is also *nix based OS kernel. You _should_ be aware of the system being working on.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire do you know which standart libraries i have to use? can you help me? is it <dirent.h>?

Comment: The extension is the part after the `.` so find the `.` and the extension is the part after that.

Comment: Yes, the functions `opendir` and `readdir` from `<dirent.h>` are what you want.

Comment: dirent.h isn't a langauge-standard header; it's POSIX (which is available on your mac, so go nuts).

Comment: @SteveSummit is <dirent.h> only for Linux like they said? thank you for helping (:

Comment: @zquab firstly, it seems you are Turkish because in English standart is written as _standard_. Secondly, the website makes use of standard libraries and macos while doing this. https://iq.opengenus.org/traversing-folders-in-c/

Comment: @zquab `<dirent.h>` is from Unix and works fine on Unix, Linux, and MacOS.  (A Windows programmer might have trouble using it, though.)

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire yes that's right sorry for that haha. thank you, you really helped me a lot.

Comment: @user253751 well not exactly, in many file systems you can put dots in file names, so that won't always work. Moreover, on *nix systems hidden files start with a dot, but that doesn't make the part after that the extension :)

Comment: `system("find . -name '*.txt'")`

Comment: @mikyll98 every filesystem that has extensions has them as the part after the dot in the filename. That's what a file extension is. If it does something different, it's not a file extension.

Comment: @user253751 what about hidden files? ^^"

Comment: @mikyll98 what about them?

Comment: @user253751 is the part after the dot of a hidden file its extension? I don't think so :)

Comment: @mikyll98 actually many tools will say yes! but if there is more than one dot, it's the part after the last dot

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to work on macOS only, you can use macOS native frameworks instead of standard libraries, like this:

```
#include "CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    CFStringRef extension  = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, ".txt", CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
    CFStringRef folderURLString = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "file:///Users/mousetail/Downloads/", CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
    CFURLRef folderURL = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, folderURLString, NULL);
    
    CFURLEnumeratorRef enumerator = CFURLEnumeratorCreateForDirectoryURL(NULL, folderURL, kCFURLEnumeratorDefaultBehavior, NULL);
    while (true) {
        CFURLRef fileURL = NULL;
        CFURLEnumeratorResult enumeratorResult = CFURLEnumeratorGetNextURL(enumerator, &fileURL, NULL);
        if (kCFURLEnumeratorSuccess == enumeratorResult) {
            CFStringRef fileURLString = CFURLGetString(fileURL);
            if (CFStringHasSuffix(fileURLString, extension)) {
                CFShow(fileURLString);
            }
        } else if (kCFURLEnumeratorEnd == enumeratorResult) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    CFRelease(enumerator);
    CFRelease(folderURL);
    CFRelease(folderURLString);
    CFRelease(extension);

    return 0;
}
```